# Simple javascript regular expression to strip numbers

Tags: javascript, regex

All I want is to strip all the numbers from a string.

So

```
var foo = "bar01";
alert(foo.replace(/\d/,''));
```

Which obviously gives "bar1" because I've only specified one digit.  So why doesn't this work:

```
var foo = "bar01";
alert(foo.replace(/\d*/,''));
```

Which gives "bar01"

Comment: Already found the answer, it's `.` rather than `*`

Comment: Unfortunately not. What you have mentioned will work in the specific "bar01" case, because you say to match a digit followed by any character. This won't remove digits at the end of strings, or more than 2 digits max, etc. See the other solutions for the better solution.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You must add the `global` option

```
var foo = "bar01";
alert(foo.replace(/\d/g,''));
```

Clearly you can even do something like

```
var foo = "bar01";
alert(foo.replace(/\d+/g,''));
```

but I don't know if it will be faster (and in the end the difference of speed would be very very very small unless you are parsing megabytes of text)

If you want to test http://jsperf.com/replace-digits the second one seems to be faster for "blobs" of 10 digits and big texts.

Comment: Not sure if it is faster or slower, but using `/\d+/g` for the regex would make more sense.

Comment: @GregL In the end if you are removing all the digits, the first one makes more sense. With the first you are removing all the digits one at a time, with the second you are searching for "blobs" of digits (one or more digits long) and removing them. An human would think in the second way (because humans have a more "global" view), machines in the first way.

Comment: Which one makes more sense is a matter of opinion, but I was just curious how the JS engine worked under the covers - whether it would be more efficient to have the regular expression engine replace whole blobs of numbers at once, or single digits individually. It probably varies per JS engine.

Comment: @GregL As I have told, I don't know. There is a site to do this types of comparisons, but I don't remember its name

Comment: @GregL Created test cases on jsperf.

Comment: @xanatos Yeah, I just did a jsPerf test as well. It would be interesting to compare the two: http://jsperf.com/regex-global-sequence-vs-single-digit. In either case, though, I was right - `/\d+/g` _is_ faster.

Comment: @GregL Technically in none of the comments you wrote what was faster :-) The first one was `Not sure if it is faster or slower` and finished in `would make more sense` so I thought it was "from a human POV make more sense"

Comment: @xanatos Fair point, I was using conjecture until I benchmarked it myself on jsperf. Now I know for sure (at least on the browsers it has been tested with).

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to specify the `g` flag: `foo.replace(/\d/g,'')`

Answer (score 2):

```
alert(foo.replace(/\d+/g,''));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the 'global' flag:

`foo.replace(/\d*/g,'')`