# Regex - delete numbers from string

Tags: php, regex

I'd like to find a regex expression to remove numbers from string Only if the char before any number is not alphabetic or is a whitespace. 
For instance:

```
_123
(1234
.12345
?!8
hi 123
?? 1234
```

will be

```
_
(
.
?!
hi
??
```

on the other hand:

```
aaa123
A1234
Z_L12345
..A8
aaa a123
```

will be:

```
aaa123
A1234
Z_L12345
..A8
aaa a123
```

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: @vks I thought the language was not necessary, I'm using PHP. Edited.

Comment: **char before any number is not alphabetic** then how come `A1234` became `A`?

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3363005/how-to-remove-numbers-from-a-string-with-regex

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7847223/simple-javascript-regular-expression-to-strip-numbers

Comment: sorry, it's corrected now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[ ]\d+|(?<=[^a-zA-Z0-9\n])\d+
```

Try this.Replace with `empty string`.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/mE6hO4/5

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to add this: `123 hi` will remain `123 hi`, how can I do that too?

Answer (score 1):

Search for this regex:

```
([^a-zA-Z0-9])(?!^)\d+
```

Replace by:

```
$1
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/lV7pI5/3)

Answer (score 1):

use the **lookbehind assertion** for this, for example for your case use look behind for `behind of your match case, it can't be "A-Z" or "a-z" or "0-9"` then you should create a set from these and insert it to look-behind.

this is your regex

```
(?<=[^a-zA-Z0-9])\d+
```

and this is your demo

```
http://regex101.com/r/dN8sA5/21
```

then you should replace it with `NULL` string.

**Edit:**
it's very better to `Trim` your final string with one of these approach

1. **Use Regex:** `\s*(?<=[^a-zA-Z0-9])\d+\s*`
2. **Use Trim:** after the replacing your string, use `String.Trim` for removing arounding space with the string.

*I really prefer the first approach...*

for more information about look-behind see this:

http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html